# C# decrypt data which encrypted in Javascript

Tags: javascript, aes, encryption

How to decrypt the encryption data generated http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html in a C# application!

Answer (score 2):

The site you have linked deals with AES encryption.

You may want to look at the RijndaelManaged class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx

Here is an article discussing the differences between AES and the Rijndael algorithm:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2006/10/09/the-differences-between-rijndael-and-aes.aspx

Comment: thanks. even RijndaelManaged : I can't find any article which show how to encrypt in javascrypt and decrypt in C#, I tried lots of ways